# FFmpeg: Image scrolling, with green background?

Tags: ffmpeg

Good morning, I hope you are well.

Please, I need help with the following...

I'm moving an image vertically, and I see that the background of the video is green.
How can I change this background color?

Example code:

ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 24 -i "image.jpg" -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x360[background];[background][0:v]overlay=shortest=1:y='min(0,-(t)*26)'" -qscale 1 -y out.mpg

Video Result: https://youtu.be/98rKLVO56wA

I hope I can help,

Thank you very much,
Greetings,
Hugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 24 -i "image.jpg" -filter_complex "color=000000:s=640x360[bg];[bg][0]overlay=shortest=1:y='min(0,-(t)*26)'" -qscale 1 -y out.mpg
```

The color filter takes RGB values as hex `RRGGBB`